# Something wrong with TextDatasetFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene, jena

I am working with Text Search using Jena and Lucene. After i run it, there are some errors. It shows at `Dataset ds = TextDatasetFactory.createLucene(ds1, dir, new TextIndexConfig(entDef));` and `Dataset ds = createCode();`. My full code shows in below:

```
public class JenaTextSearch {

static {LogCtl.setLog4j();
    BasicConfigurator.configure();}
static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("JenaTextSearch");

public static void main (String ...argv)
{
    Dataset ds = createCode();
    //loadData(ds, "data.ttl");
    queryData(ds);

}

public static Dataset createCode()
{
    //base data
    Dataset ds1 = DatasetFactory.create();
    Model defaultModel = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    defaultModel.read("to_index/data.ttl", "N-TRIPLES");
    ds1.setDefaultModel(defaultModel);


    //define the index mapping
    EntityDefinition entDef = new EntityDefinition ("uri", "text", ResourceFactory.createProperty(App.URI_PREFIX,"content"));

    Directory dir = null;

    try {
        dir = new SimpleFSDirectory(Paths.get("index")); //lucene index directory
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //join together into a dataset
    Dataset ds = TextDatasetFactory.createLucene(ds1, dir, new TextIndexConfig(entDef));

    return ds1;

}

public static void queryData(Dataset dataset)
{
    String prefix = "PREFIX email: <" + App.URI_PREFIX+">" +
            "PREFIX text: <http://jena.apache.org/text#>";

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Email's content contains 'good'");
    String query = "SELECT * WHERE " +
            "{ ?s text:query (email:content 'good'." +
            " ?s email:content ?text . " +
            " }" ;

    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.READ);
    try {
        Query q = QueryFactory.create(prefix+"\n"+query);
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, dataset);
        QueryExecUtils.executeQuery(q, qexec);
    }finally { dataset.end();}
    long finishTime = System.nanoTime();
    double time = (finishTime-startTime)/1.0e6;
    System.out.println ("Query "+String.format("FINISH - %.2fms", time));

    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Email's content contains 'bad'");
    query = "SELECT * WHERE" +
            "{ (?s ?score ?lit) text:query (email:content 'bad' \"highlight:s:<em class='hiLite'> | e:</em>\") ." +
            " ?s email:content ?text . " +
            " }" ;

    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.READ);

    try {
        Query q = QueryFactory.create(prefix+"\n"+query);
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, dataset);
        QueryExecUtils.executeQuery(q, qexec);
    } finally { dataset.end() ; }
    finishTime = System.nanoTime();
    time = (finishTime-startTime)/1.0e6;
    System.out.println("Query "+String.format("FINISH - %.2fms",  time));
}}
```

Since i am a newbie, literally i don't get what's wrong with it. Maybe it get matter in TextDatasetFactory or something. Please advise me.

p.s: i got these codes from [this](https://www.atjiang.com/jena-text-full-text-search-with-external-content/) and nothing wrong from there.
p.s again: the errors show just when i compiled it (red line in console) like below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper
at org.apache.jena.query.text.TextDatasetFactory.createLuceneIndex(TextDatasetFactory.java:109)
at org.apache.jena.query.text.TextDatasetFactory.createLucene(TextDatasetFactory.java:136)
at main.JenaTextSearch.createCode(JenaTextSearch.java:70)
at main.JenaTextSearch.main(JenaTextSearch.java:42)
```

**JenaTextSearch.java** is the project with the errors.

Comment: Shows what errors? Include the errors in the question.

Comment: @greg-449 i've added the error description. may it helps

Answer (score 0):

"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" -- that is an error from Java saying something is missing.  It's the jena-text dependencies missing (here, Lucene) from the classpath at runtime.

It is better if you use a build tool like maven or gradle.

The dependencies include: (this is taken from `mvn dependency:tree`; `mvn dependency:build-classpath` will build a classpath for you and print it out if you want to include it elsewhere).

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:7.4.0:compile
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i have added it to my maven. but it shows other errors like `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/SimpleAnalyzer`

does it need the same way to fix it?

Comment: `SimpleAnalyze` is in `lucene-analyzers-common` - you have to add all the dependencies. Using tools like maven or gradle help with this.